# Way to use @Convert to convert key of a Map (JPA)?

Tags: java, jpa, converters

I am using java.time.LocalDate of Java 8, and want to convert that to sql date so that it can be persisted. Here is my converter:

```
@Converter(autoApply = true)
public class LocalDatePersistenceConverter implements
    AttributeConverter<LocalDate, Date> {

        @Override
        public Date convertToDatabaseColumn(LocalDate attribute) {
        return java.sql.Date.valueOf(attribute);
        }

        @Override
        public LocalDate convertToEntityAttribute(Date dbData) {
        return dbData.toLocalDate();
        }

}
```

Here is how it is getting used:

```
@Entity
@Access(AccessType.FIELD)
public class MutualFund implements Serializable {

    @Id
    private final String schemeName;

    @Convert(attributeName="key",converter=LocalDatePersistenceConverter.class)
    @ElementCollection
    private Map<LocalDate, Price> nav;

    //Other fields and methods
}
```

When I try to persist a MutualFund object, I get following exception:

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: @Convert placed on Map attribute [mypackage.MutualFund.nav] must define attributeName of 'key' or 'value'
```

What is wrong in this code? Please help. Thanks.

Comment: That looks correct to me. Are you sure you're running the code you showed us? Unrelated: schemeName shouldn't be final.

Comment: @JBNizet Yes. However, I haven't done any configuration of "LocalDatePersistenceConverter" any where. It's simply annotated and then used in MutualFund class as shown.

Comment: I have put schemeName as final because, once declared the name of the mutual fund scheme doesn't change during its life.

Comment: It does: JPA first instantiate the entity by calling its no-arg constructor, and then it sets the value of the field using reflection.

Comment: Yes, but logically it doesn't change. I don't want some one to just set the name of mutual fund anytime. For JPA, I have provided no-arg constructor with packaged private access.

Answer (score 3):

Your mapping of the Map is not completed so you are getting the exception.

There are two options for Map mapping, not sure which one you were trying to achieve.

A) The LocalDate key of the nav map is a field of the Price object:

```
@Embeddable
public class Price implements Serializable {
    @Convert(converter=LocalDatePersistenceConverter.class) 
    //you don't need @convert if it is annotated with @Converter(autoApply = true)
    public LocalDate mark;
    public double price;
}
```

Then in your collection mapping you need to specify the key field used:

```
@ElementCollection
@MapKey(name="mark")
public Map<LocalDate, Price> nav;
```

B) The key element of nav is not part of the Price object, then you need to explicity map it to a column:

```
@Embeddable
public class Price implements Serializable {
    public double price;
}
```

and the map annotation:

```
@Convert(converter=LocalDatePersistenceConverter.class)
@ElementCollection
@MapKeyColumn(name="mark")
public Map<LocalDate, Price> nav;
```

EDIT
It turned out that Hibernate is most demanding than EclipseLink

With @Converter(autoApply = true) it works without pointing to the converter with both explicit and implicit key column.

```
@ElementCollection
@MapKeyColumn(name="mark") //this annotation can be omitted then the key column is called nav_KEY
public Map<LocalDate, Price> nav;
```

I could not make it work without autoApply. Persistence context could be build only if converter was declared with attributeName="key.":

```
@Convert(attributeName="key.", converter=LocalDatePersistenceConverter.class)
@ElementCollection
public Map<LocalDate, Price> nav = new HashMap<>();
```

but the converter was not correctly apllied. During schema generation the key column was tried to be generated as BLOB (and failed as no length was given) and serializaton instead of conversion was triggered during insert/fetching. I could not find a way to fix it.

Comment: Hi Zielu, my case is the second one. I tried your solution but I am still getting the same exception.

Comment: I tested it with EclipseLink, which JPA you are using?  It also works without convert anotation (when @Converter(autoApply = true) is on the converter class) so you may try to remove it. And in my example I am not using the attribute name=key.

Comment: also do not use key as the name of the column @MapKeyColumn(name="key"), alhtough key is not reserved I discovered problems with querying if the key is used as field/column name.

Comment: I am using Hibernate. I tried all the combinations , but its throwing the same exception :( .

Comment: I will try tomorrow with hibernate

Comment: See the update. With hybernate It could only work with @Converter(autoApply = true), and no @convert annotation on top of the map. If you cannot use autoApply for some reason, you have not other option as declare the key attribute inside your price embedable which should not be a big issue.

Comment: I really appreciate all your efforts Zielu!!! I tried the updated solution, but converter is not getting activated. Then hibernate creates tinyblob for Date, and it fails while creating a foreign key with schemeName and LocalDate (mark-tinyblob). I simply tried persisting a LocalDate field, but converter is not getting called, it creates tinyblob for LocalDate. Do you think I need to configure the converter in some other way? As of now, I have kept that in same package and annotated it and thats it.

Comment: Update: I had set autoApply = false, and then used it with a simple LocalDate field, explicitly mentioning the converter class there. I worked fine. It's just not working with Map somehow.