# How to map a map JSON column to Java Object with SpringD Data JPA

Tags: spring-data-jpa

I'm using springboot, MYSQL(with a column type JSON) and 
I'm getting below error message when trying to convert JSON field to Map in Entity

Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: @Convert placed on Map attribute com.anil.99acres.model.mysql.SellerAPIDetailsModel.fieldMapping] must define attributeName of 'key' or 'value'

### Codes

```
@Converter(autoApply = true)

public class JsonToMapConverter
        implements AttributeConverter<String, Map<String, Object>>
{
    private final Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(this.getClass());

    @Override
    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    public Map<String, Object> convertToDatabaseColumn(String attribute)
    {
        if (attribute == null) {
            return new HashMap<>();
        }
        try
        {
            ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
            return objectMapper.readValue(attribute, HashMap.class);
        }
        catch (IOException e) {
            logger.error("Convert error while trying to convert string(JSON) to map data structure.");
        }
        return new HashMap<>();
    }

    @Override
    public String convertToEntityAttribute(Map<String, Object> dbData)
    {
        try
        {
            ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
            return objectMapper.writeValueAsString(dbData);
        }
        catch (JsonProcessingException e)
        {
            logger.error("Could not convert map to json string.");
            return null;
        }
    }
}
```

**Entity**

```
@Column(name = "FIELD_MAPPING", columnDefinition = "json")
@ElementCollection
@Convert(attributeName = "data", converter = JsonToMapConverter.class)
private Map<String,Object> fieldMapping =new HashMap<>();
```

!!!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to map mysql JSON column to JPA / Hibernate - Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44308167/how-to-map-mysql-json-column-to-jpa-hibernate-java)

Comment: If you see, the code is exact same of the post you mentioned but still I'm getting another error.

Comment: Sorry, I missed that. Now it looks more like this one https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29861951/way-to-use-convert-to-convert-key-of-a-map-jpa

Comment: Tried same but no luck!!